# How to switch keyboard layout in Openbox using keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, 19.10, openbox

I'm trying to configure keyboard layout switching by keyboard shortcut in Openbox DE.

```
$ cat /etc/default/keyboard 
XKBLAYOUT="us,ua,ru"
XKBVARIANT=",winkeys,"
BACKSPACE="guess"
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBOPTIONS="grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp:win_space_toggle,grp_led:scroll"

$ cat /etc/bash.bashrc | grep kblayout
source /home/user/.kblayout.sh

$ cat /home/user/.kblayout.sh 
#!/bin/bash
setxkbmap -layout us,ru,ua -option grp:lwin_space_toggle

$ setxkbmap -print -verbose 10
Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev:
rules:      /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us
options:    grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp:lalt_lshift_toggle,grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp:win_space_toggle,grp_led:scroll,grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete+ledscroll(group_lock)
symbols:    pc+us+inet(evdev)+group(win_space_toggle)+group(lalt_lshift_toggle)+group(alt_shift_toggle)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete+ledscroll(group_lock)"    };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+inet(evdev)+group(win_space_toggle)+group(lalt_lshift_toggle)+group(alt_shift_toggle)"   };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};

$ cat .config/gxkb/gxkb.cfg 
[xkb config]
group_policy=2
default_group=0
never_modify_config=false
model=pc105
layouts=us,ru,ua
variants=
toggle_option=grp:lwin_toggle,lv3:switch,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp,grp_led:scroll
compose_key_position=

$ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "system-keyboard"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        Option "XkbLayout" "us,ru,ua"
        Option "XkbModel" "pc105"
        Option "XkbVariant" "pc105"
        Option "XkbOptions" "grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll"
EndSection
```

For terminal window input keyboard layout could be changed with those options by <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> after I run new instance of `bash`. For new instance of `bash` it works, but not for bash in just opened terminal. `setxkbmap -layout ru` or whatever also works in terminal. In current terminal session without running new instance of bash I run `setxkbmap` command or source a script with that command. But nothing of it works in Openbox GUI applications.

I've installed `tint2` panel to be able to switch keyboard layouts by mouse clicking.

Keyboard shortcuts in **IBus Preferences** -> **Keyboard Shortcuts** do not actually change keyboard layout. Tried different keys combinations:

[image]

The same preferences somehow work in iceWM, but it works strangely there (when I type in different non-english layout, it often inputs English letters instead of Cyrillic letters. It require removing that letters a few times till letters become Cyrillic). I do not often use Cyrillic and I could log in into Unity for normal keyboard layout switching, but I want to figure out, how to configure it correctly in Openbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Openbox looks for user defined configs at `~/.config/openbox`. If nothing was there, then it looks for default config files at : `/etc/xdg/openbox/`.

Create a new user then make a copy of default config files in your user directory so we can edit them:

```
mkdir ~/.config && cp -r /etc/xdg/openbox ~/.config
```

Then add this line:

```
setxkbmap -layout "us,ru" -option "grp:alt_shift_toggle" &
```

To

```
~/.config/openbox/autostart
```

Now you can change the layout using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> after a logout and re-login.